# How to convert 3D point cloud (extracted from 3D sparse reconstruction) to millimeters?

Tags: matlab, 3d, computer-vision, pixel, point-clouds

Using Stereo vision and based on Multiple View Geometry book (http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/), I have created a 3D point cloud in MATLAB.
 To do that, I first calibrated the cameras and rectified the stereo images. Then feature extraction and matching. Then eliminated the noisy matched based on camera locations. Finally created the 3D point cloud using triangulation.

Now my question is **how to convert this 3D point cloud from pixel domain to actual millimeter/centimeter domain knowing my focal length and camera calibration matrices?**
**the goal is to find DEPTH IN MILLIMETERS.**

I know how to do it in disparity/depth map case using formula: Z=(t*f)/d. 

But here in the sparse case, can I do something like this? http://matlab.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_measure_a_distance_or_area_in_real_world_units_instead_of_in_pixels.3F
or there is a more sophisticated method with more in depth explanation?
Thanks.

Comment: Basically I want to see how I can get X,Y,Z in millimeters from the 3-D point cloud created by triangulation.

Answer (score 0):

The formula you wrote is valid only in the special case when the image planes of the two cameras are on the same geometrical plane, and the motion from one to the other is a translation parallel to one of the image axes.

In the general case you'll need to triangulate actual rays in 3D space, using one of the techniques described in that book (it has a whole chapter on reconstruction). The reconstruction will be metrical if your calibration is. In particular, if the coordinate transform between the cameras has a translation vector whose units are meters (or millimeters, or inches, ...).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this to me. I really appreciate it.  since my calibration is done using Caltech's camera calibration toolbox (http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/) and the translation vector is in millimeters (120,0,0), then my 3D point cloud after triangulation should be in millimeters as well. 
<br/> Now my question is how to interpret the 3D point cloud? I assume the Z coordinate is the distance from the camera, but it really does not make sense based on my results! Also why do I have negative values for X, and Y ?

Comment: Re-read my first and second sentence. The formula you are applying is wrong, computing it meters does not make it right. If you are (as is common) matching after rectifying the images, you need to undo the rectification and then triangulate.

Comment: But I am not using that formula! that is for dense reconstruction using disparity map! I am not going that way! I am doing sparse reconstruction . so I first calibrated the cameras, then rectified the images and cropped them, then feature extraction and matching using SIFT, then estimate fundamental matrix using Gold standard method from the book, then calculated essential matrix from camera calibration matrices, then camera matrices from essential matrix, and finally triangulation to find the 3D point cloud.

Comment: may I know why I need to undo the rectification before triangulation?

Comment: (1) Sparse triangulation: suggest to use the Hartley-Sturm method. http://www-ljk.imag.fr/Publications/Basilic/com.lmc.publi.PUBLI_Article@1176ddd04d5_10531d2/HartleySturm-cviu97.pdf  (2) Undoing the rectification: strictly speaking you don't need to do it, if you are using H-S, provided that your fundamental matrix is transformed to account for it. Besides, if you are not doing dense matching, why bother with rectification?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try that. You are right, I do not need stereo rectified images for sparse 3D reconstruction. But I still need to undistort images to remove lens distortion, right? like this example (http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/sparse-3-d-reconstruction-from-multiple-views.html#zmw57dd0e8800)

Comment: Yes. Among other things, if your images have non-linear distortion it makes no sense whatsoever to speak about fundamental matrices, since the cameras would not be linear projective devices.

Comment: Well they are calculating fundamental matrix in this Matlab example(http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/sparse-3-d-reconstruction-from-multiple-views.html#zmw57dd0e8800) and how do we find camera matrices without fundamental matrix? directly from essential matrix?

Comment: You said that your cameras are calibrated (I assume that to mean that you have the intrinsics already). Can't you just calibrate the extrinsics as well?

Comment: Yes, I have the extrinsics as well, but I want to remove outliers of features matching using epipolar constraints. to do that I need to estimate fundamental matrix.

Comment: Last comment (then you'll have to go back to the book). If your stereo pair is calibrated (both int and ext) you do not need to "estimate" the F-matrix, you can just compute it from the camera matrices and the left-to-right camera pose matrix [R|t]. Use it to remove outliers, then throw it away and triangulate the inliers.

Comment: OK I do not have extrinsic camera parameters. so I had to estimate fundamental matrix and build the 3D point cloud using triangulation. Now I have my 3D point cloud in pixels. how can I convert it to millimeters?